# How to copy files and file structure with a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch script that does a myriad of things.  The one part I am stuck on is copying files/file structure from a location to my final image.  The file structure looks something like this

```
Foo
|->Bar
|  |->Snafu
|  | |-><FILES>
|  |-><FILES>
|->Bar2
|  |->Snafu
|  | |-><FILES>
|  |-><FILES>
|->Bar3
|  |->Snafu
|  | |-><FILES>
|  |-><FILES>
etc...
```

I want to copy the whole contents of the Folder Foo while maintaining the file structure.  Here is the rub...this has to be able to run on a clean copy of Windows, so I cannot use any third party programs (which leaves out XCOPY, etc.).

I have tried using the "copy" command with various parameters, but the closest I get is getting the files with no folder structure.  I am not always sure what is in the folders, so I can't even hard code it.

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please in future use the `tree` command `%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com Foo /F` or `%SystemRoot%\System32\tree.com Foo /F /A` and copy and paste that instead of a non understandable structure like your current submission. Also, we expect you to post the code which is failing for you, not be expected to simply provide working code, please see [mcve], for more information, and try to read through all of the pages of [ask] too. Also please open a Command Prompt window, type `robocopy /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its usage information. `RoboCopy` & `XCopy` are built into the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XCOPY, which is way better than COPY.

XCOPY is NOT a third party command, there's no need for software. It was added back in 1986 (MS-DOS 3.30, correct me if I'm wrong), so every Windows OS has it.

Command would be: `xcopy /y /h /i /e foo bar`

Which will:

- Copy all directories structure, including empty directories (`/e`)
- It won't prompt for confirmation
- Hidden files will be also copied.

Comment: I had thought that XCOPY was third party.  I am so glad that it is in Windows.  This makes this soooooo much easier.  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: `XCopy` was superceded by `RoboCopy`, way back in [tag:Windows-Vista], please therefore try to use `Robocopy`, which is most of the time a better option, rather than resorting to the deprecated `XCopy` utility.